# Is there a tool to see task manager that is historical? How do I investigate?

Tags: task-manager

My task manager shows 100% CPU usage. It doesn't show what programs are running.

I tried to take screenshot and nothing is shown. So I wait while playing games. After a while I got this

[image]

It was empty before and the problem is gone. However, I have no idea what caused the problem.

Is there a way I can see tasks that is historically time consuming?

Comment: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile`  leave to capture the issuen then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl` .  You can open the trace with WPA - Windows Performance Analyzer which you can get from the MS Store or by installing the SDK - Performance Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Under the tab “Performance”, there is a link at the bottom to open the Resource Monitor. This gives you a very detailed view on the various performance aspects of your computer, including a history graph. It has a history graph, but no advanced data collection to playback something that has happened.

A (more advanced and more complex) tool you can use for that purpose is the “Performance monitor”. You can start it by running “perfmon” from the run box (Windows key + r). The Performance monitor lets you collect data there for “analysis after the fact”, so I think that tools best fits your requirements.

See for example [this Microsoft blog about the Resource Monitor](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/using-resource-monitor-to-troubleshoot-windows-performance/ba-p/375008) for a more elaborate discussion about that tool and its use and a similar article [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10) about the Performance monitor.